# Room database is not working in mac book pro m1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

Room database is not working in mac book pro m1
i have already added  id 'kotlin-kapt'

[screen shoot of android studio console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWT3f.png)

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)    ... 31 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for
> os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64
> at
> org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:333)
> at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:64)
> at
> androidx.room.verifier.DatabaseVerifier.(DatabaseVerifier.kt:71)
> ... 50 more

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply use Room 2.4.0-alpha03

```
def room_version = "2.4.0-alpha03"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Edit : The answer consisted of two solutions to solve the issue , since the above written solution was successful for many ,the other solution is removed .

Comment: def room_version = "2.3.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0'
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

Comment: facing this error after added 2.4.0-alpha03
import androidx.room.migration.AutoMigrationSpec;
                              ^
  symbol:   class AutoMigrationSpec
  location: package androidx.room.migration

Comment: Add the error and your gradle file  to your question in detail

Comment: Solution B is what worked for me. Much obliged!

Comment: Solution B worked for me.

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar Currently I am working on 2 android project, both on mac m1, but   1st project building fine with room 2.1.0-beta01 and other giving same issue as above. Any idea on this?

Comment: Can't tell the issue . Try invalidating the cache and rebuilding . Such issues happen with AS a lot .

Comment: But "kapt" is not replaceable by "annotationProcessor". What if I need to use it with Kotlin? –

Comment: Use kapt in place of annotationProcessor then

Answer (score 1):

add dependency:
kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"

Comment: How does this solves the problem, can you please elaborate?